# Delphi Chromium Embedded (vers. 1) memory deallocation after unloading resources

Tags: delphi, memory-management, chromium-embedded

I am using Delphi Chromium Embedded (DCEF . vers. 1) in my application.
I have noted that when Chromium loads some heavy resource (html page with many components, big javascript code, ...), when content is left It doesn't de-allocate memory (as observed in Task Manager). 
The same operations with Chrome browser have as a result the expected de-allocation...
How is it possible to force Embedded Chromium to do the deallocation ?
Is there any instruction to 'refresh' memory or something similar ?
Or some configuration ?

Comment: You know that Task Manager is not a good way to measure memory allocation? Are you seeing issues with dcef or not, what does the built-in memory leak detection tell you? Eg Fastmm4 [ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown)?

Comment: @whosrdaddy the memory will be allocated by the chromium DLLs surely and so not tracked by delphi mm

Answer (score 1):

CEF 1 runs in single process mode and is deprecated. Use CEF 3 which has a multi process architecture similar to Chrome/Chromium and behaves more like Chrome in regards to memory management.

Comment: Ok, I'm aware of that, but now we are still using CEF1 and urgently need a way to manage memory. Is it possible ?